# Laptop speakers show up as multiple devices

Tags: sound, plasma

In my audio controls (Settings -> Audio, or the volume controls in the panel), I see multiple different "devices" for my built-in laptop speakers.

Playback Devices:

- Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller Pro
- Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller Pro 3
- Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller Pro 4
- Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller Pro 5
- Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller Pro 31

Recording Devices:

- Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller Pro
- Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller Pro 6
- Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller Pro 7

Of the output devices, two of them don't produce sound, two of them produce normal-ish sound, another produces weird-ish sound.

Each of them can switch between "Off", "Play HiFi quality music" and "Pro Audio". Currently all of them are on "Pro Audio".

What could be the reason? How can I "fix" it?
In general I only want to see one device for my laptop speakers.

#### System information

(This is *not* Kubuntu - I installed Plasma manually on top of standard Ubuntu)

```
Operating System: Ubuntu 23.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.27.4
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.104.0
Qt Version: 5.15.8
Kernel Version: 6.2.0-36-generic (64-bit)
Graphics Platform: X11
Processors: 8 × 11th Gen Intel® Core™ i7-1165G7 @ 2.80GHz
Memory: 15,3 GiB of RAM
Graphics Processor: Mesa Intel® Xe Graphics
Manufacturer: LG Electronics
Product Name: 17Z90P-G.AA79G
System Version: 0.1
```

[image: Audio settings]

[image: Audio panel]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I detected the same issue today on Debain 12 and discovered a solution that resolved it.
You can simply click the "burger" button and choose "Play HiFi quality Music" instead of selecting "Pro Audio."
I hope that this solution will work for you as well.

Andrei.

Comment: Interesting, now I only have 3 items instead of 5.
Still weird though.

Comment: Maybe the multiple channels have something to do with "surround" audio?

Comment: On my HP laptop, after selecting 'Play HiFi quality Music,' I see four sliders.
The first two are for output channels (speakers and headphones). And the last two are for the laptop's microphone and headphone`s microphone.